# Vuetable-2 cannot be mounted in Laravel 6

Tags: laravel, vue.js, datatable, laravel-6

I'm trying to use the Vue component [Vuetable-2](https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2-with-laravel-5.4) in Laravel 6. I know the component says that it's made for 5.4, but I believe it should still work.

My `app.js` looks like this:

```
    require('./bootstrap');

    window.Vue = require('vue');

    Vue.component(
      'example-component',
       require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default
    );
    Vue.component(
      'my-vuetable',
      require('./components/MyVuetable.vue')
    );

    const app = new Vue({
      el: '#app',
    });
```

The console reveals that the component could not be mounted.

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.
>
> found in
>
> ```
> ---> <MyVuetable>
>        <Root>
> ```

The `view` to where I'm trying to mount the component is the following:

(note that the example component does mount correctly)

```php
@extends('layouts.app', ['activePage' => 'integracion', 'titlePage' => __('Integracion')])

    @section('content')
      <div class="content" id="app">
        <div class="container-fluid container">
          <example-component></example-component>
          <my-vuetable></my-vuetable>     
        </div>
      </div>
    @endsection

    @push('js')
      <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

        });
      </script>
    @endpush
```

Comment: `.default` at the end.

Comment: at the end? of the app.js or what do you mean?

Comment: `require('./components/MyVuetable.vue')` -> `require('./components/MyVuetable.vue').default`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `require('path').default`. The `.default` is necessary here because when you use `require('path')` you're just getting a JSON object back:

```
{ default: <VueConstructor> }
```

So no template or render function is defined within that object. However if you use `.default` then you will actually get back an SFC in this case which can be transpiled down.

The alternative would be to use `import`:

```
import MyVuetable from './components/MyVuetable.vue'
Vue.component('my-vuetable', MyVuetable)
```

Or alternatively, with `syntax-dynamic-import` enabled:

```
Vue.component('my-vuetable', () => import('./components/MyVuetable.vue'))
```